# Outputting to 2 decimal places

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the following to output to 2 decimal places:

```
$("#incP1").click(function(){
  $(":text[name='qty1']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty1']").val()) + 1 );
  $(":text[name='cost1']").val( Number($(":text[name='cost1']").val()) + 1.99 ) ;
});
```

I've been trying to use toFixed(2), but with no luck. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(":text[name='qty1']").val( (+$(":text[name='qty1']").val() + 1).toFixed(2) );
```

Comment: `"1" + 1 = "11"` in js. You'll need `parseInt` or `parseFloat` before.

Comment: @Tommi sorry, forgot a (+)